# Expressing Feynman propagator with absolute value instead of Heaviside step function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, propagator

I recently saw an interesting paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.13435, where the author wrote the Feynman propagator of free massless scalar field as
$$
D_F(x-x') = -i\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} e^{-i\omega (t-t')}\frac{e^{i|\omega||\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}}{4\pi |\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}.
\tag{1}
$$
(Please see their equation (2.18).)

While they wrote the Wightman propagator
$$
W_0(x-x')=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} e^{-i\omega (t-t')}\frac{\textrm{sin}\omega|\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}{2\pi |\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}.\tag{2}
$$
(This is their equation(2.19).)

Equation (2) is easy to derive, but when I tried to write the equation (1), I only got this
\begin{align}
D_F(x-x') &= \theta(t-t')W_0(x-x') + \theta(t'-t)W_0(x'-x)\tag{3}\\
&=\theta(t-t')\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} e^{-i\omega (t-t')}\frac{\textrm{sin}\omega|\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}{2\pi |\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|} \cr
&+ \theta(t'-t)\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} e^{-i\omega (t'-t)}\frac{\textrm{sin}\omega|\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}{2\pi |\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}\tag{4}\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} e^{-i\omega |t-t'|}\frac{\textrm{sin}\omega|\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}{2\pi |\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|}.\tag{5}
\end{align}
I have tried to separate the sin$\omega |\vec{x}-\vec{x}\,'|$ into two Exponentials and switch the $\omega \to -\omega$ in the integrand, but it didn't look similary to (1) at last. I cannot get rid of the absolute value $|t-t'|$ and I also have problem to get the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Honestly, I haven't seen a Feynman propagator like equation (1) before, all the textbooks I met express it as a piecewise function or the addition of two theta functions as equation (3).

Do you have any idea of how to transform (5) to (1)? All suggestions would be welcome.